# What is "ROAM" related to terrain rendering?

Tags: graphics, terrain-rendering, level-of-detail

I saw it mentioned on [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9/whats-the-newest-trend-method-for-terrain-rendering), but no one explained what it is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ROAM stands for "Real-time Optimally Adapting Meshes." It is a level of detail algorithm for rendering large terrains. It's somewhat complicated so I'll link to some more in depth explanations:

Here is the paper: https://graphics.llnl.gov/ROAM/roam.pdf

The following is a slightly less academic explanation: http://www.yaldex.com/game-programming/0131020099_ch14lev1sec4.html

Comment: +1 Gamasutra also has a very nice and easy to understand explanation of ROAM: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3188/realtime_dynamic_level_of_detail_.php

Comment: It should be noted that many developers are now shying away from complicated LOD systems because of their tendency to hog CPU.  GPU's are at the point where often just throwing a bit more geometry is preferable to stealing valuable CPU.

Comment: Move along to other algorithms, ROAM was relevant when the fill cost of triangles on screen was high, and it was worth the CPU time to cut them down as much as possible.

Comment: Have a look at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9/whats-the-newest-trend-method-for-terrain-rendering. Never use ROAM, there are better alternatives available.